# My JavaScript variable will not change the position of the image

Tags: javascript

```
let h;
function getRandomIntH() {
return Math.round(Math.random() * 250);}
h = getRandomIntH();

$('#gamespace').append('<img src="transparent.gif" style="left: 100px; top: h; width: 100px; height: 100px;">');
```

I made a function above that makes a random number, but whenever I try and use it to move my image, it inputs as zero instead of the number stored in the variable.

Comment: left/top/right/bottom only effect elements positioned relative/absolute/fixed - of those, the correct one depends on you

Comment: $('#gamespace').append('<img src="transparent.gif" style="position: absolute;left: 100px; top: '+h+'; width: 100px; height: 100px;">'); You have to change code like this.

Comment: I tried it with 250px as top and it moved, but it didn't work with the variable. I even used alert and the variable does have a random number stored in it.

Comment: You aren't using the `h` variable.

Comment: also, more to not using `h` ... you need a unit, not just a number ... e.g. 250px, not 250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the last line with this so that you're using the value from the h variable instead of setting top to the string "h":

```
$('#gamespace').append(`<img src="transparent.gif" style="left: 100px; top: ${h}px; width: 100px; height: 100px;">`);
```

Comment: surely it's `top: ${h}px;`

Comment: Whoops, you're right, I fixed it. Thanks :)